# Searching a list of names in a text file from user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm currently in an Introductory Java class at University and I'm having a bit of trouble. Last semester we started with Python and I became very acquainted with it and I would say I am proficient now in writing Python; yet Java is another story. Things are alot different. Anyway, Here is my current assignment: I need to write a class to search through a text document (passed as an argument) for a name that is inputted by the user and output whether or not the name is in the list. The first line of the text document is the amount of names in the list.
The text document:

```
    14 
Christian 
Vincent 
Joseph 
Usman
 Andrew
 James 
Ali 
Narain
 Chengjun 
Marvin 
Frank 
Jason
 Reza 
David
```

And my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DbLookup{

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        File inputDataFile = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputDataFile);
        int length = inFile.nextInt();
        String names[] = new String[length];

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            names[i] = inFile.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter a name that you would like to search for: ");
        while(stdin.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Please enter a name that you would like to search for: ");
            String input = stdin.next();
            for(int i = 0;i<length;i++){
                if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(names[i])){
                    System.out.println("We found "+names[i]+" in our database!");
                    break;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I am just not getting the output I am expecting and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Also a side note; a requirement of the assignment is to use the Scanner class; I know something like BufferedReader would be more efficient, I just need to follow the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
You should `trim()` your values as they have extra spaces

```
 if(input.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(names[i].trim()))
```

I have run your example it runs perfectly after using `trim()`,  you have missed to `trim()`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate `scanner` class to read line by line.You can use `BufferedReader` also.

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   final String str= scanner.nextLine();
   if(str.contains(name)) { 
       // Found the input word
       System.out.println("I found " +name+ " in file " +file.getName());
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8:

```
String[] names;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    names = stream.skip(1).toArray(size -> new String[size]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```